# How specify header file location to GCC on WSL

Tags: c, gcc, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL through VSCode and trying to compile a C file called voltagereader.c using gcc. The code has the following dependency: `#include <NIDAQmx.h>`

But whenever I try to compile the code gives me an `gcc: error: NIDAQmx.h: No such file or directory` error even though the I am able to find the NIDAQmx.h file in this location on my pc: `C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\NI-DAQ\DAQmx ANSI C Dev\include`

On the WSL terminal I can find this file on this location: `/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/National Instruments/NI-DAQ/DAQmx ANSI C Dev/include/NIDAQmx.h`

I tried multiple methods to compile the code including these and I keep getting the same error.

> gcc voltagereader.c -o voltagereader gcc voltagereader.c NIDAQmx.h -o
> voltagereader
>
> gcc voltagereader.c /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/National
> Instruments/NI-DAQ/DAQmx ANSI C Dev/include/NIDAQmx.h -o voltagereader
>
> gcc -I voltagereader.c /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/National
> Instruments/NI-DAQ/DAQmx\ ANSI\ C\ Dev/include/NIDAQmx.h
> voltagereader.c NIDAQmx.h -o voltagereader

How can I make sure that gcc can find this header file correctly?

Comment: -I "full path of includes"

Comment: With the -I option, I get undefined reference to 'Functions defines in .h file' errors. How can I move forward from there?